# Where did http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles go?

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am working through some course material from Sun (now oracle) to learn something new (Web-Services to be precise). And it is lesson one and when running the example web page I am greeted with:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/pages/layout.jsp(3,74) PWC6188: The absolute uri: http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

I located the problematic line:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
```

And now I am at a loss. And I know Sun should provide better example. But can anybody help me?

Comment: Sadly, Sun doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That taglib was actually part of [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org). You need to install it in order to get those taglibs to work (just download the JARs and drop them in `/WEB-INF/lib`). However, Tiles grew up out of Struts and became independent almost a decade back. See also [their homepage](http://tiles.apache.org).

> Tiles grew in popularity as a component of the popular Struts framework. **It has since been extracted from Struts** and is now integrated with various frameworks, such as Struts 2 and Shale .

Read [up-to-date tutorials about webservices](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnayk.html) ;) Start with [Tiles docs](http://tiles.apache.org/framework/index.html) if you want to keep using Tiles for some reason. The new taglib URI is

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
```